# send file to s attachment of email through jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to send attachment of email. I want to do it from jquery ajax but I tried with jquery ajax to file type. I am not successful. If anyone how use this help me to solve this.

```
<?php
 <form action="../PHP/sendemail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="upload" name="upload">
<table>
<tbody>
 <td style="width: 190px;padding-right: 0px ">
   <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" id="uploaded_file" class="text-center center-block well well-sm"><br>
 </td>
 <td>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" value="Apply Now" id="btn<?= $row['vacancyid']?>" name="btn<?= $row['vacancyid']?>">
 </td>
</tbody>
</table>
?>
<script>
$('#upload').click(function(event){

    var FormData = new FormData($(form)[1]);

    $.ajax({
        url : "sendmail.php",
        data : {FormData:uploaded_file},
        type : 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success : function(data){
        alert(data); 
        }
    });
  }
```

Thank you...

Comment: @Mahendra Gunawardane if you have a solution for my quection help me

Comment: I will take a look at the questions, But I my php skills a limited.

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena i want to solve this from Jquery ajax.if you can solve this inform me

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail

Comment: @AlonAlexander i can send email with attachment.but i want to post file and email through ajax

Comment: @DanithKumarasinghe I don't see the problem... In your php file make sure you got the `FormData` in the post and then send an email with it as attachment... What exactly are you asking in the question?

Comment: @AlonAlexander i want to send e mail with attachment.attachment must be only pdf.i want to send that pdf file through jquery ajax and when email successfully send get alert without refreshing page.

Comment: @DanithKumarasinghe Check out this page, I think it has EXACTLY what you want: https://www.sanwebe.com/2012/06/ajax-file-upload-with-php-and-jquery
But of course you need to send the file instead of saving it...